# Copy value of column into another column

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013 list there is multiple line of text column A and there is another multiple line of text column B. I want to copy text from column B into column A only on item edit, so in edit form.

I thought I will do it quickly but I can't solve it.
What I tried was

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#columnA").val($("#columnB").val()); 
});
```

EDIT
part of edit form page where I added IDs is bellow

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
          <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>A</nobr>
          </H3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="columnA">
         <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="A" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@A')}"/>
         <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="A" ControlMode="Edit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <nobr>B</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="columnB">
      <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="B" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@B')}"/>
      <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="B" ControlMode="Edit"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code / a fiddle please?

Answer (score 1):

The 'columnA' and 'columnB' is in different row?
You want to set 'columnB' value from the pre-row 'columnA', and loop this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr:has(columnA)').each(function(this){
    var aVal = $(this).find('columnA').html();
    $(this).next().find('columnB').html(aVal);
  });
});
```

Code above is you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsFiddle of how you could use jQuery `each` to solve the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/pyn20ogc/

@Dalton 's approach is different but similar, probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make it based on @TKoL example:

```js
$('#run').click(function() {
    $('tr td').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).text()
        $(this).next().html(value)
    })
})
```

```css
table td {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="first">a</td>
  <td class="second"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="first">b</td>
  <td class="second"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="first">c</td>
  <td class="second"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<button id="run">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it similar to what I asked in question, but I put IDs of DIVs instead of TDs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#.._TextField_inplacerte").text($("#.._TextField_inplacerte").text());
});
```